# Lombok Conditional ToString.Include

Tags: java, lombok

Lombok supports the @ToString.Include to allow custom formatting of an attribute when printing the Object or attribute.  I'm considering using this feature to mask PII data when logging to a log file.  I still want to include the field in the log but I need it to be masked.  However, adding this annotation always masks the field.  Is there a way to make this conditional?  The issue I'm having is that when debugging, the field is masked.  I'd really like the field to be masked only when I indicate it should be masked i.e. when logging to a log file.

Comment: Actually, this is not an issue when debugging.

Comment: Can you show your code and explain with an example input/output ?

Comment: `toString` is for debugging. Invent a new method for logging if logging is a feature in your program.

Answer (score 5):

After experimenting with this, I'm happy with the way this is working.  My main concern was that I would lose the ability to view the attribute values while debugging.  That is not the case of course.  When I log the object it applies the toString function for the object and masks the attributes I want to mask.  But I can still view the attribute values in the object.

As an example, if I set emailAddress = testemail@gmail.com I can print an EmailAddress Object and it will print EmailAddress(emailAddress=t********@gmail.com)

```
@Builder
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public final class EmailAddress {
    private final String emailAddress;

    // replace all characters after the first character with a *
    // up to the @ symbol
    @ToString.Include(name = "emailAddress")
    private String fieldMasker() {
        return emailAddress.replaceAll("(?<=.{1}).(?=[^@]*?@)", "*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer @Mike, however, are you not going to use `@ToString.Exclude` on `emailAddress` ?

Comment: No, we want to log the entire Object.  EmailAddress an object included in a hierarchy of objects.  I want to log the entire hierarchy but mask fields that are considered PII.